# Unexpected output using react-router-dom with React's Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-context

For a small project of mine, I'm trying to implement the most basic authentication as possible, using the React context API without Redux.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'

export const AuthContext = createContext()

export const useAuth = () => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext)

    if(context === null) throw new Error('Nope')

    return context  
}

export const AuthProvider = (props) => {
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false)

    const login = () => {
        setAuthenticated(true)

        localStorage.setItem(storageKey, true)
    }
    
    const logout = () => {
        setAuthenticated(false)

        localStorage.setItem(storageKey, false)
    }
    
    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{authenticated, login, logout}} {...props}/>
}

export default AuthContext
```

I created a context, and wrapped my `<App />` component in it like so; `<AuthProvider></App></AuthProvider>`. Because I want to keep the authenticated state, I used the browser's local storage, for storing a simple boolean value.

```
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'
import { useAuth } from './context/AuthContext'

import { AuthPage } from './pages'

import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Switch,
    Route,
} from 'react-router-dom'

import { useEffect } from 'react'

const App = () => {
    const { login, authenticated } = useAuth()

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('user')

        if(token && token !== false) { login() }
    })

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/auth" component={AuthPage} />
                <Route exact path='/'>
                    Dashboard
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default App
```

Then, in my `<App />` component, I tried invoking the `login` callback, given from the `AuthProvider`, which made me assume that made me login during page refreshes. When I try to access the `authenticated` variable in the current component, it does work. It shows that I am authenticated.

However when I try to set up a PrivateRoute, which only authenticated users can go to like this:

```
import {
    Route,
    Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom'

import { useAuth } from './context/AuthContext'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const { authenticated } = useAuth()
    
    if(authenticated) {
        return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => <Component {...props} />} />
    }

    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

It does not work. It just redirects me to the login page. How does this come? The `PrivateRoute` component is getting rendered from the `<App />` component. Also, what would be the solution to this problem?

Comment: `useEffect` is called _after_ `PrivateRoute` component has mounted and by the time its called which in turn calls `login` function, user has already been redirected to the `/login` route.

Comment: Inside the `PrivateRoute` component, check the value of the `authenticated` _only after_ `login` function has been called. Created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-tree-981pf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that shows you how you can solve the problem. (try changing the value of `token` variable inside the `useEffect` hook)

Comment: This demo above is great.  Seems best to just keep up with a loading status for auth, which allows components to render, but you can use the loading status to essentially wait for auth to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than running a `useEffect` on every rerender to check if user should be logged in, you should better initialize your `authenticated` state with the values from your localStorage:

```
const storageKey = 'user'
const initialState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey)) ?? false

export const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(initialState)

  const login = () => {
      setAuthenticated(true)

      localStorage.setItem(storageKey, true)
  }
  
  const logout = () => {
      setAuthenticated(false)

      localStorage.setItem(storageKey, false)
  }
  
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{authenticated, login, logout}} {...props}/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Yousaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6094348/yousaf) for the explaination in the comments and the [HospitalRun](https://github.com/HospitalRun/hospitalrun-frontend) project on GitHub, I made a loading state in the `<App />` component.

```
import { useAuth } from './context/AuthContext'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import Router from './Router'

const App = () => {
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true)
    const { login } = useAuth()

    const token = localStorage.getItem('user')

    useEffect(() => {
        if(token && token !== false) { 
            login()
        }

        setLoading(false)
    }, [loading, token, login])

    if (loading) return null

    return <Router />
}

export default App
```

Here I only let anything render, after the `login` function was called.

```
if (loading) return null
```

If this could be done any better, feedback would still be appriciated!

Comment: I would say that `loading` is a redundant state since it's the opposite boolean value from `authenticated`, right? I imagine you could consume `authenticated` instead. It seems your `useEffect` is for initial state purposes, since every subsequent execution comes from `login|out` being called somewhere else. If you try to initialize your state with localStorage value(which is a common approach) as I suggested I believe you could only check `authenticated` directly if I'm not mistaken.